# Select String Based on Iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to practice my Javascript using CodeWars and I'm still in the beginner phase of learning. I've gotten stuck on this one question and I am hoping someone can explain to me in the most simplest way how to iterate (I believe that's what it's called) through numerous strings based on a number input.

Here is the question:

> You pick a petal off a flower saying each of the following phrases
>   each time a petal was torn:
>
> I love you
>
> a little
>
> a lot
>
> passionately
>
> madly
>
> not at all
>
> Your goal in this kata is to determine which phrase you would say for
>   a flower of a given number of petals, where `nb_petals > 0`.

So far I have this:

```
function howMuchILoveYou(nbPetals) {

var petalSaying = ["I love you", "A little", "A lot", "Passionately", 
"Madly", "Not at all"];

for(var petals = 0; nbPetals > 0; nbPetals--);
}
```

And I'm not sure where to go after this to get it to print out the string necessary based on the number input for `nbPetals`.

Also, if the number input is `7` for example, it would output `I love you`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The question is pretty poorly worded. Do you say each of the phrases for every petal that is torn out, or one of the phrases for each petal that is torn out?

Comment: The phrase is only displayed once all the petals are torn out. So if the flower has 8 petals, by the end it should print out, "A little."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do iteration, just access the given array element by index. If the number is more than the number of elements, use modulus to wrap around.

```
function howMuchILoveYou(nbPetals) {
    var petalSaying = ["I love you", "A little", "A lot", "Passionately", "Madly", "Not at all"];
    var index = (nbPetals - 1) % petalSaying.length;
    return petalSaying[index];
}
```

`nbPetals - 1` adjusts for the fact that array indexes start at `0`, but `nbPetals` starts at `1`.

Comment: Thanks for that response, I don't think I would have ever come up with that. Could you explain what the modulus is doing in this case?

Comment: It does what modulus always does, it returns the remainder of the division. So you get clock-style arithmetic that wraps around.